# y-axes of Highcharts line chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

If I create a line chart with Highcharts and set the minimum value of the y-axes to the smallest value in my data series (0 in the example below), then the points along the y-axes (circled below) are not connected. Is there a way to connect them.

[image]

Comment: use min value on y-axis. [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/xaxis/min-max/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known Highcharts bug: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1687

As suggested, you can set lineWidth: 0 for xAxis.

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to put the min value to something below zero like this:

```
yAxis: {
    min: -0.1   
}
```

so you will now see the values that are at 0.

And set startOnTick to false

Comment: and set startOnTick to false.